# install specific version of chromium by source code

Tags: chromium, selenium-webdriver

I need to run the source code of Chromium(86.0.4240.197) which is in a tar.gz package. However, when I extract the package runnig `tar xf chromium-86.0.4240.197.tar.gz` nothing happens. . Is there another way to build it?

Comment: After extracting the archive you need to configure, build, and install the resulting binary. There is probably a readme or install doc in the newly extracted folder with the exact commands.

Comment: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code this is the site linked to the readme however the explanation of Application Startup seems very unclear.